# error with PUGXMultiUserBundle

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle

i installed PUGXMultiUserBundle using this documentation **https://github.com/PUGX/PUGXMultiUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md**
i have two isues : 
    first i don't know where i should put the User Manager

```
$discriminator = $this->container->get('pugx_user.manager.user_discriminator');
$discriminator->setClass('Acme\UserBundle\Entity\UserOne');

$userManager = $this->container->get('pugx_user_manager');

$userOne = $userManager->createUser();

$userOne->setUsername('admin');
$userOne->setEmail('admin@mail.com');
$userOne->setPlainPassword('123456');
$userOne->setEnabled(true);

$userManager->updateUser($userOne, true);
```

and other thing when i try to run register page , i have this error :

```
UserDiscriminator, error getting form type : "MyApp\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationUserOneFormType" not found
```

Thank you for yourhelp

Comment: Does the form exist? Also, what do you mean by "i don't know where i should put the User Manager"?

Comment: i already add the form by myself i did't find it  in the documentation , and in any part of the project i should put it